# .htaccess redirect to WWW with current htaccess code?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect my URLs to the `www` version. I can do this, but I already have working `.htaccess` code that is redirecting the browser to my index.php file where the URL is processed. I have this code (which I did not write), and I do not know enough about `htaccess` to figure the problem out:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /index.php [NC]
```

I have tried simply using the full URL path in the redirect, but this produces a 404 error when I attempt to access pages. I have also attempted to simply include more rules underneath this code, with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want http://example.com/foo/bar to redirect to http://www.example.com/foo/bar?

If so, this should do the trick, while preserving your intent

```
RewriteEngine On

# First redirect non-www hosts (the "L" flag means we won't process
# any more rewrite conditions in this redirect; on the next request,
# the rewrite condition won't match and we'll fall through to your 
# original rule)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]  

# Handle normal requests
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /index.php [NC]:
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thank you for the quick response!